# Three text bodies not aligning with inline-block

Tags: html, css

I cannot get three texts centered on the same line: “5/1 ARM”, “30 Year Fixed” and “15 year fixed”. As you can see, the “30 year fixed” is much higher.

I am very new to this, so I have tired everything I know thus far.

```css
.loans {
  margin-top: 15%;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.loans h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.loanLenghs {
  clear: both;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.rates {
  clear: both;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Chalarangelo/mini.css/v3.0.1/dist/mini-default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  HTML:
  <div class="loans">
    <h1>Our awesome rates!</h1>
    <div class="loanLenghs">
      <p style="margin-bottom: 0;">30 Year Fixed</p>
      <p style="float: left">15 Year Fixed</p>
      <p style="float: right;">5/1 ARM</p>
    </div>
    <div class="rates">
      <p style="float: right">%4.552</p>
      <p style="float: left">%3.999</p>
      <p style="text-align: center;">%5.332</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I expected the “30 year loan” to be on the same line as the others.

Comment: can you please put screenshot so i could understand what you want actually.

Comment: The `<p>`s need to be `inline-block`, not the containing `<div>`.

Comment: Use a table it's made for this situation, a bunch of tabular data.

Comment: yes, thank you. Using .loanLenghs p { display: inline-block;  } seemed to work. Thank you,

Comment: hi, just add css properties -  `display: flex;justify-content: space-around;` in your `.loanLenghs` class selector - Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .loans {
            margin-top: 15%;
            padding-bottom: 150px;
            background-color: lightblue;
        }
        .loans h1 {
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }
        .loanLenghs {
            clear: both;
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }
        .rates {
            clear: both;
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }
        .left {
            width: 30%;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .center {
            width: 30%;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .right {
            width: 30%;
            display: inline-block;
        }
```

```html
<div class="loans">
        <h1>Our awesome rates!</h1>
        <div class="loanLenghs">
            <p class="left">30 Year Fixed</p>
            <p class="center">15 Year Fixed</p>
            <p class="right">5/1 ARM</p>
        </div>
        <div class="rates">
            <p class="left">%4.552</p>
            <p class="center">%3.999</p>
            <p class="right">%5.332</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [flex](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp)

```css
.loans {
  margin-top: 15%;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.loans h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.loanLenghs,.rates {
  display: flex;
}
.loanLenghs p, .rates p {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Chalarangelo/mini.css/v3.0.1/dist/mini-default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  HTML:
  <div class="loans">
    <h1>Our awesome rates!</h1>
    <div class="loanLenghs">
    
      <p style="">15 Year Fixed</p>
        <p style="">30 Year Fixed</p>
      <p style="">5/1 ARM</p>
    </div>
    <div class="rates">
      <p>%4.552</p>
      <p >%3.999</p>
      <p>%5.332</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line in your CSS file

```
.loanLenghs {
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.loanLenghs p {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And Also, remove the inline CSS

```
          <p>30 Year Fixed</p>
          <p style="float: left">15 Year Fixed</p>
          <p style="float: right;">5/1 ARM</p>
```